# Is it advisable to use for comprehensions with yield to return a huge number of items?

Tags: scala

I am working on a little program that generates combinations and I am using `for` comprehensions. Something like this:

```
def posibilities2(n: Int): Seq[List[Int]] = {
  val maxValues = (1 to 3).map(i => n / i).toList
  for {
    n1 <- 0 to maxValues(0)
    n2 <- 0 to maxValues(1)
    n3 <- 0 to maxValues(2)
    if n1 * 1 + n2 * 2 + n3 * 3  == n
  }
    yield List(n1, n2, n3)
}  

posibilities2(1000).foreach(doSomething)
```

For bigger values of n it can lead to lots of items.

My question is this: Is this the way to do it, given that, for each item generated, I have to do some additional processing? I am not concerned about the program taking a long time to run, I am concerned about running out of memory.

Thank you

Comment: Are you asking if the `for` expression in particular needs more memory than other solutions that do the same thing, or are you asking how not to run out of memory when creating large collections in general? These problems are two entirely different things.

Comment: @JFo: I was asking whether using the yield pattern as I coded it above is suitable for returning lots of items. pamu's answer fits what I wanted to do. However, I am new to Scala and I have to admit I don't know the inner workings and the fine details of different choices - for instance using the iterator vs. the form I used. I still have to do a lot of reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As amount of values for-comprehension produces is very high its better to go for `iterator` or `stream` implementation.

The below function will generate values on demand basis thus not risking out of memory errors.

```
  def posibilities2(n: Int): Iterator[(Int, Int, Int)] = {

    val maxValues = (1 to 3).map(i => n / i).toList
    for {
      n1 <- (0 to maxValues(0)).toIterator
      n2 <- (0 to maxValues(1)).toIterator
      n3 <- (0 to maxValues(2)).toIterator
      if n1 * 1 + n2 * 2 + n3 * 3  == n
    } yield (n1, n2, n3)

  }
```

Comment: Thanks. That is what I was looking for.